# request not sent to server

Tags: php, post, flutter, httprequest

I'm trying to build a log in page where I retrieve the user name and password values and store them in two variables that I send to my php file where I search wether the values exist or not and then in the onPressed button I handle both cases. I used both post method and Dio() but none of them work since my data is not sent. Here are both methods :

with Dio()

```
Future postData() async {
    Response response = await Dio().post(
        "http://192.168.0.117/testlocalhost/annonces/LogIn.php",
        data: {"User_name": userName, "password": password}
        );
}
```

with post

```
Future postData() async {
 var url = "http://192.168.0.117/testlocalhost/annonces/LogIn.php";
    http.post(
        url,
        body: {"userName": "$userName", "password": "$password"}
        );
 }
```

(userName and password are the varibales where I store the user's input)

here is the php file that searches wether the values exist or not

```
 <?php
   require('TestLocalHost.php');

   $makeQuery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE User_name=userName  AND   
   password=password";

   $stamement = $connection->prepare($makeQuery);

   $stamement->execute();
 ?>
```

and here's the onPressed method

```
onPressed: () {
         userName = userNameController.text;
         password = passwordController.text;
             if (postData() == null) {print("ERROR!");}
             else{print("Done"):}
              },
```

Comment: Is `postData` called?

Comment: yes in the if Statement of the onPressed method

Comment: What I meant to ask was is the function `postData` called? Try adding a `print("called");` in `postData` and check whether it is called or not.

Comment: Are you able to hit this endpoint using Postman or curl? Also, are you getting an exception in the app or it is just not responding? You're also not awaiting the result and are also not catching the exception here as well.

Comment: @10101010 you're right the Dio() is apparently not working since the print i put in the bottom of postData didnt print anything. ut the post method is woring just fine ecause it printed

Comment: @aubykhan yes i have this error : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 192.168.0.117, port = 58261

Comment: Can you use `curl` or Postman to hit http://192.168.0.117/testlocalhost/annonces/LogIn.php ? 
if the above is successful, you can try opening this url from your emulator/device browser. I think the server is not configured correctly.

Comment: @aubykhan i tried curl 192.168.0.117/testlocalhost/annonces/LogIn.php , and i got this result : curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.117 port 80: Timed out

Comment: It looks like there's a firewall enabled on your server or somewhere in the route to your server which is preventing requests from outside to reach your server. Once you are successful in that then we can move to code and see if it works and then fix it.

Comment: @aubykhan i disabled all the firewalls but i still get the same message

Comment: Are you sure the server is running? Can you hit it through localhost from the server itself?

Comment: I think you should port this issue for server troubleshooting first and then come back here if the issue with your Flutter app persists.